# IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: How to use Pathlib correctly

Tags: python, image, pathlib, data-preprocessing, abbyy

```
image_folder = Path("path_to_image_folder")

def get_preprocessed_image(image_path: pathlib.Path) -> PIL.Image.Image:
    with image_path.open("rb") as image_input:
        return PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(pyabbyy.preprocess(image_input.read())))


def preprocess_image_folder_(image_folder: pathlib.Path) -> None:
    for image_path in tqdm.tqdm(list(image_folder.rglob("*.pdf"))):
        get_preprocessed_image(image_path).save(image_path)

pyabbyy.initialize_engine(
        "h8KSSy98TGLEint",
        "path_to_activation_token",
        "password",
        "path_to_profile.ini",
)

# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':

    get_preprocessed_image(image_folder)
```

What is to be altered here? I want to preprocess folder of images. It is using ABBYY service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please include the full traceback of the error, to make it easier to see the issue for us.
My guess would be that you are calling `get_preprocessed_image` on `image_folder`, but that function expects a path to an image, not a folder.
Instead, call the other function:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':

    preprocess_image_folder_(image_folder)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. But now I get an exception

Comment: I get the above exception though. Could you help please ?

Comment: Could anyone have a look at this traceback ? Thank you.

Comment: Please include the traceback in your question, not as an edit of my answer :)

Comment: From the traceback, it looks like one of the files (named `_`) contained in the folder you are going through is password-protected, so you can ignore it in the loop, or catch the exception in the loop, and keep it running :)

Comment: Could you please give an example on how to catch it?

Comment: Could you please explain and show how to write it ?